# Adding numbers using button to a textbox

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm new to programming and I have a problem. I have two buttons and a textbox. When I press the button, a number will show on the textbox, but when I press the second button the number in the textbox overwrites it and replaces it instead of adding to it in the textbox. How do I fix this? I want the values to *add* instead of *replacing* it.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    int value1 = 0;
    int value2 = 0;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        value1++;
        textBox1.Text = value1.ToString();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        value2 += 2;
        textBox1.Text = value2.ToString();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: `textBox1.Text = (int.Parse(textBox1.Text) + value2).ToString();`

Answer (score 4):

If you want to add two *integers* and assign the result back to `textBox1` you have to

1. *Parse* `textBox1.Text` to integer: `int.Parse(textBox1.Text)`
2. *Sum* up values: `int.Parse(textBox1.Text) + value2`
3. *Convert* the outcome back to `string`: `(...).ToString()`

Implementation:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { 
  value2 += 2;

  textBox1.Text = (int.Parse(textBox1.Text) + value2).ToString();
}
```

**Edit:** If there's a possibility that `textBox1.Text` doesn't contain a valid integer value (say, `textBox1.Text` is empty) you can use `int.TryParse`:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { 
  if (int.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out var v)) {
    value2 += 2;
    textBox1.Text = (v + value2).ToString();
  }
  else {
    //TODO: textBox1.Text is not a valid integer; put relevant code here 
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using two separate variables (`value1` and `value2` above) to store the results of each button click, depending in which button was clicked. Think of it like this:

```
On program start:
value1 = 0
value2 = 0
```

User clicks button 1, which executes button1_Click. This increments value1 (via `value1++`), so the two variables look like this:

```
value1 = 1
value2 = 0
```

User then clicks button 2, which executes button2_Click. This sets value2 to whatever was previously in value2 + 2. However, note that the value of value1 is unchanged:

```
value1 = 1
value2 = 2
```

By having separate variables, each button click is operating on a different value. I would modify your code so there is only one `value` variable that both _Click functions modify.

Comment: this gives an alternate idea for how to store the value, but does not answer the question about how to add the value to the text property of the text box...

Answer (score 0):

Add this line:

> textBox1.Text = (int.parseInt(textBox1.Text) + value2).toString();

after

> value2 += 2;

into your button2_click method: